# TypeScript Object.assign confusion

Tags: typescript

When I look at the [signature of `Object.assign`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4405) I see that it uses intersection types, but the behavior is not what I expected.

I want to use `Object.assign` to merge some changes with an old object to create a new object (as is common practice in JS when following immutable data patterns) and have TypeScript validate that the parts and the result are correct, but it seems TypeScript allows anything through without an error.

For example:

```
interface Thing {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    fav: boolean;
}

let oldThing: Thing = {
    name: "Aaa",
    age: 123,
    fav: false
};

let newThing: Thing = Object.assign({}, oldThing, {
    name: "Bbb",
    age: "abc", // should be type error
    fake: "fakey" // should be unknown prop error
});
```

[Here it is in the playground.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Thing%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fav%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20oldThing%3A%20Thing%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22Aaa%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20123%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fav%3A%20false%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20newThing%3A%20Thing%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20oldThing%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22Bbb%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20%22abc%22%2C%20%2F%2F%20should%20be%20type%20error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fake%3A%20%22fakey%22%20%2F%2F%20should%20be%20unknown%20prop%20error%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A)

Why does `Object.assign` allow this incorrect assignment to `Thing`? Is there a way to make this work close to what I expected?

Comment: You've met all the requirements to make the typescript compiler happy, but remember at the end of the day it's javascript that runs your code and javascript just doesn't care.

Comment: Yep, I'm reminded of that all the time. :) But my question here is why does it *compile*? It seems the assignment to `Thing` should be a compile error on those properties. Maybe I don't understand how the type checker validates assignment.

Comment: It's been almost 3 years, still no progress with `Object.assign`. I'm kind of confused as to why there's so little information about this issue. I think it should be described in official docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you intuitively expect an error here is that the intersection type constructed for the return value of `Object.assign` is absurd, and cannot be occupied by any real values. However, TypeScript has no way of verifying this. The return value from `Object.assign` here is typed as the following:

```
{
    name: string,
    age: string & number,
    fav: boolean,
    fake: string
}
```

Of course there is no actual value that is both `string & number`, but the compiler doesn't know that. It happily constructs this absurd type, then when you try to assign it to `Thing` verifies that the type of each property in `Thing` is satisfied by the corresponding property in the return value. Since this is the case (each of `name`, `age` and `fav` are present, and satisfy at least the required interface in `Thing`), the assignment succeeds.

If you allowed the type of `newThing` to be inferred, then tried assigning anything to the `age` property, you'd see the problem:

```
let newThing = Object.assign({}, oldThing, {
    name: "Bbb",
    age: "abc",
    fake: "fakey"
});
newThing.age = 10;   // Compiler error because 10 is not a string
newThing.age = "10"; // Compiler error because "10" is not a number
```

Comment: Thanks, that *is* funky. So I guess `Object.assign` doesn't really help enforce type-safety for things like this. Looking forward to TS supporting object spread instead...

Comment: It's probably a new development since 2016, but there's a name for `string & number`: `never`. The compiler knows it has no values, but it's fine to have an object with a field of type `never` so long as you don't try to assign to it. (The compiler *will* allow you to read from it and will implicitly convert it to any type, which sounds weird, but `never` is really meant for things like the return type of a function that always throws an error.)

Comment: @JohnWilliams Yes, `never` is the absurd type, and it does appear that `string & number` now evaluates to `never`. It's not clear to me that in general the compiler is capable of reducing an arbitrary intersection type to `never` when it has no inhabitants (given how sophisticated the type system is), but it'd be pretty cool if we have that property now.

Answer (score 8):

You can force TypeScript to check using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions): i.e.,  `as Thing` or `<Thing>`

```js
interface Thing {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    fav?: boolean;  // You may need to mark this as optional depending on
                    // your requirement, otherwise TypeScript will 
                    // generate missing prop error
}

//...

let newThing: Thing = Object.assign({}, oldThing, {
    name: "Bbb",
    age: "abc",     // will cause type error
    fake: "fakey"   // howerver, no error for unknown prop
} as Thing);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thanks! I did not know I could specify the object's type with `<Thing>{ ... }` syntax.

Comment: With newer reversion of Typescript (since version 4 I think) it's better to use "satisfies" than "as" because it just checks the type rather than casting.